# iOS Swift Alamofire cachePolicy

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

In `Alamofire` version 3 I use `NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.returnCacheDataDontLoad` for request cache

```
let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    URLRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.returnCacheDataDontLoad
    Alamofire.request(URLRequest){...}
```

But how can I use cachePolicy in Alamofire 4 and swift 3?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I searched everywhere and ended up with this :

```
    let TheURL = DEFAULT_APP_URL + "api/getList?Id="+ID
    let urlString = NSURL(string: TheURL)
    var mutableURLRequest = URLRequest(url: urlString! as URL)
    mutableURLRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    mutableURLRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.returnCacheDataElseLoad


    Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
        .responseJSON
       {....}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my piece of working code.

```
    private static func request(_ showHud: Bool = true, urlString: String,
                            httpMethod: HTTPMethod,
                            parameters: [String : Any] = [:],
                            headers: [String : Any] = [:],
                            success : @escaping SuccessBlock,
                            failure : @escaping ErrorBlock) {
    var additionalHeaders: HTTPHeaders?
    additionalHeaders = headers as? HTTPHeaders
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    if !(NetworkReachabilityManager()?.isReachable ?? false) {
        urlRequest.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataDontLoad
    } else {
        showIndicator(showHud)
    }
    urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = additionalHeaders
    urlRequest.httpMethod = httpMethod.rawValue
    do {
        urlRequest = httpMethod == .get ? try URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters) : try JSONEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
    } catch {
        failure(NSError(localizedDescription: "Something went wrong!"))
    }
    Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<ResponseHandler>) in
        parseResponse(response, success: success, failure: failure)
    }
}
```

The key is before loading data from cache I checked for internet connectivity. If internet is available I show the loader and it loads the api and if not it gives me data from cache.